# How can a messaging server indetify target client and send push notification

Tags: java, networking, push-notification, client-server, instant-messaging

My clients are Android devices. A client wants to send some info to another client which will first be sent to the app server and then the server will notify a middleware service(some kind of message broker) which will be responsible for sending the target client a push notification(to tell it to poll from the app server).
I want to know:
**How will this middleware service identify which client device to notify?**
more concretely, **How does a push notification server locate which physical device to fire off the notification to?**
My requirement is that the client should be able to obtain notifications even while using a VPN or proxy(similar to WhatsApp). Also, if the client is powered off then the middleware queues the messages and delivers them once the client power backs on again.
I have been looking at things like Firebase Cloud Messaging and MQTT brokers and stuff but I want to implement similar things on my own.
I want to implement this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your client ( **having an unique id and token** ) will send the message to another client who also have **a unique id and token in the database** .. So the,

> Server will map the receivers' id to the receivers token and send the notification to the receiver..

The database(backend) will have unique ids (maybe primary keys) against each client and also a unique token (for sending notification) against each client. So , when the sender-client sends the message , the backend script maps the receiver-client's (to whom the sender is sending) `id`  to the receiver clients token. Then send the notification to the particular token.

Comment: How will the server find out which exact client? What if the client is changing networks? How will my server establish a contact with my client to even begin with? The client has the IP address of the server, but the server knows nothing of the client(and the middleware service as well which will do the messaging).

Comment: @Shankhadeep no matter whatever the network is the sender will target the receiver ..the backend will send the notification to the receiver id.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say. But my real question is, **How will the middleware service know which actual Android device to send the notification to in real time?** The client doesn't poll unless it gets the notification from the sever. If the client is powered off, the messages get queued in the middleware and sent when the client powers up.

Comment: that is a `networking` concept.. i explained how the backend the system actually work..

Comment: But I need information about how the transport happens. I understood all the part about the mapping of keys and tokens. I have already incorporated them into my architecture. Do you have some kind of detailed explanation or sources that explain this in detail? I want to fully understand this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165989/discussion-between-santanu-sur-and-shankhadeep-ghoshal).